# How to get comments on TFS

Tags: java, jira, tfs-2015

Scenario is:

1. I opened a tab on my Jira called *My Tab* – it just works like other tabs. [java](/questions/tagged/java)
2. I have TFS 2015, I wrote a TFS server-side plug-in to check if user uses tags like [Example] my comment [/Example] in their check-in otherwise the comment gets rejected. [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)
3. This step is where I am stuck:
   I want to reach TFS to get the comment that are between [Example][/Example] tags. When I click *My Tab*, I want to see all the
   comments between these tags related to this issue (its subtasks are
   included).

Example:

> *username* submitted changeset #1 to http://localhost:8080/tfs
>
> 11/1/2016 5.35 PM
>
> [Example] My first comment [/Example]
>
> issue ID: 124

---

> username2 submitted changeset #2 to http://localhost:8080/tfs
>
> 11/2/2016 10.30 AM
>
> [Example] My comment is the second one [/Example]
>
> issue ID: 124

---

> username3 submitted changeset #65 to http://localhost:8080/tfs
>
> 11/2/2016 5.30 PM
>
> [Example] My comment is under the subtask, issue ID is different
>   [/Example]
>
> issue ID: 125

---

How can I do this using the Java SDK? I want to implement my own, I don't want to use any plugins.

Comment: Are you looking for tf changeset [changesetnumber] command?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT Looking for the comment I write on Visual Studio when I check-in

Comment: tf changeset [changesetnumber] command will get the comment you have checked in.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT Can you explain in a snippet?

Comment: It's a command line, you can use it in your java code. Check https://www.visualstudio.com/sl-si/docs/tfvc/changeset-command

Comment: @Cece-MSFT I wrote a basic http client and

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.get("/_apis...", null), I need that ... part, can I put it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TFS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-ca/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets#get-a-changeset) to get a changeset, then you can get comment value in the Response:

```
GET http://({server:port})/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets/{id}?api-version=1.0
```

Comment: or   **'GET http://({server:port})/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets?api-version=1.0'** 
for all changesets